# RStudio "next line" command in browser() does not work

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I thought, that you can use the browser() command in RStudio to step through lines in code. In many cases this works. However, in R scripts it seems it does not work. Here is a minimal example (Just copy the following code in test.R):

```
print("1")
browser()
print("2")
wrong # Produces error, which can not be tracked using browser
print("3")
```

(R-3.3.0, RStudio 0.99.489).
Any help is appreciated!

**Thanks to @Batanichek, the following script solves the problem:**

```
{
print("1")
browser()
print("2")
wrong
print("3")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you right

You can pass all your script into `{}`

like

```
{
+ print("1")
+ browser()
+ print("2")
+ wrong # Produces error, which can not be tracked using browser
+ print("3")
+ }
[1] "1"
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> n
debug at #4: print("2")
Browse[1]> n
[1] "2"
debug at #5: wrong
Browse[1]> n
Error: object 'wrong' not found
```

then `run` will stop at `browser()`

Or if source

```
source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
[1] "1"
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n
debug at ~/.active-rstudio-document#4: print("2")
Browse[2]> n
[1] "2"
debug at ~/.active-rstudio-document#5: wrong
Browse[2]> n
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'wrong' not found
```

Comment: Yes, it does stop. But then it continues with the whole script instead of going through step by step. I think `Browse[1]> n` does not work.

Comment: hmm.. for me it works step by step RStudio 0.99.896 , R-3.2.5

Comment: Ok. This works. But as test.R script it doesn't work. Does it also work if you run it as .R script "source" (= Ctrl + Shift +S)?

Comment: Yes its also work in source ( see edit) , but wihout {} not works

Comment: Now I got it. Does that make sence to you or is it a bug?

Comment: This worked for me, but I do not understand why it does!